# How to escape dot character using String.format

Tags: java, string-formatting

Using Java 8, I would like to get this code block :

```
System.out.println(String.format("Hello %.", "world"));
```

Results in :

```
Hello world.
```

But unfortunately gets :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.UnknownFormatConversionException: Conversion = '.'
 at java.util.Formatter.checkText(Formatter.java:2579)
 at java.util.Formatter.parse(Formatter.java:2565)
 at java.util.Formatter.format(Formatter.java:2501)
 at java.util.Formatter.format(Formatter.java:2455)
 at java.lang.String.format(String.java:2940)
```

How could I escape this dot character, which seems to have a special meaning ?

Comment: I think you want `"Hello %s."`

Answer (score 2):

`System.out.println(String.format("Hello %s.", "world"));`